# Plugin section in Maven for dependency tree

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to print dependency tree as per [`dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) for multimodule Maven project and firing the command

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree
```

works perfectly in this case.

For mentioning additional configurations such as **creating aggregate dependency graph and writing to external directory**, I made following changes in `pom.xml`.

```xml
<profile>
      <id>java-src</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
---
---
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>tree</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
---
---
 </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

On running `mvn tree`, it is not working as expected and gives following error:

`[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "tree". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]`

Kindly help regarding the same.

Comment: try `mvn depndency:tree`

Comment: `tree` is not a phase of any [Maven standard lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

Comment: @tgdavies ... without the typo. :)

Comment: Oops yes, `dependency`!

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with this:

1. As tgdavies already tried to point out, you need to call `mvn dependency:tree`.
2. You defined the configuration in an execution bound to the `compile` phase. This means that the usual build (like `mvn clean package`) will create the dependency tree, but the configuration is not directly usable from command line. While you *can* call such an execution from command line by using `@`-notation, it is more advisable to move the configuration out of the execution block so that it can be used by vanilla calls to `mvn dependency:tree`.